# ODBC dbase driver: read string field directly omitting codepage interpretation usage

Tags: odbc, ado

I'm using ADO connection and ODBC driver to read DBF file:

```
Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Extended Properties=dBase IV;
```

How can be string fields fetched without chars convertion (according to some codepage)? I mean, is there any way to read strings just like array of bytes.
Perhaps, some Property of ADOConnection or connection string advancing affects the behaviour of strings reading.

P.S.: Any dbf-file modifications are not acceptable.

I've already tried to advance connection string with the following parameters: "AutoTranslate=no;"; "CCSID=65535;". But it did not work. I still have characteres translation corresponding to some codepage

Answer (score 0):

One more interesting moment. If to connect via OLE DB provider

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;
```

then chars translation is skipped.
But this method is slow and has some disadventages, therefore it doesn't fit well.

Currently, I have not found solution except using Jet OLE DB provider in case of incorrect strings autotranslation and MSDASQL provider as a common one for general purpose...